# Display zip codes based on selected states

Tags: jquery

I would like to know whats the best way to display zip codes based on selected state.
I have a database in MySQL with all cities and zip codes from the USA.  I would like to make a query to mysql which I already have, but to display the data, for example if I select from a drop-down box - state Florida, I want to display all cities, then I select city and then display all zip codes..

1. select a state (cities appear)
2. select city (zip codes appear)
3. zip codes (only a few that are allowed)

Comment: Nobody's going to want to select a ZIP code from a lengthy list, especially when so many have trained their fingers to type it in without even looking.

Comment: yeah I don't need help with the MySQL part, I have to specify that not all zip codes are allowed so we can't let them type in zip codes.. I just need to know whats the best approach and a few links to sample stuff to play with it..

Comment: In a first step I would allow everything and validate the zipcode against the selected state server-side. Once I had that up and running smoothly, I'd have the browser download a mapping from state to allowed zipcodes, and do a client-side check as soon as the user enters the zipcode. Generally, you need to have tried something to ask on SO for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have a column for every entry in the table for state as well? Then do something like

```
select city from your_table where state=thestateselected
```

This will display all cities.

Then do something similar for the zip codes to get all zip codes in the city

```
select zipcode from your_table where city=thecityselected
```